# How should I avoid this race condition?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, race-condition

I have a piece of code like below which is truncated for concise:

```
        bargained_count = BargainLog.objects.filter(bargain_start_log=bargain_start_log).count()
        ...
        money = calc_single_bargain_money(
            bargained_count=bargained_count,
            ......
        )
        ...
        BargainLog.objects.create(bargain_start_log=bargain_start_log, money=money, ...)
```

`bargained_count` is a parameter of func `calc_single_bargain_money`. But, because of the race condition, I am not sure if this is one kind of race condition. I may get `bargained_count` as same values in high concurrency which will affect the result of `calc_single_bargaiN_money`. So, how should I avoid it, please give me some advice.

Like in multi threading, I want to add a lock before getting `bargained_count` and release the lock after creating new `BargainLog` instance to ensure they are bundled together.

I have tried to use celery to handle this, but it is not convenient caused by param passing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.select_for_update()` to lock the rows until the end of a transaction. See docs [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/querysets/#select-for-update)

```
from django.db import transaction


bargain_logs = BargainLog.objects.filter(bargain_start_log=bargain_start_log).select_for_update()

with transaction.atomic():
    bargained_count = bargain_logs.count()
    ...
    money = calc_single_bargain_money(
        bargained_count=bargained_count,
        ......
    )
    ...
    BargainLog.objects.create(bargain_start_log=bargain_start_log, money=money, ...)
```

Comment: The problem still remains after I use `select_for_update` in high concurrency circumstances.

Comment: Does it really work for querying instead of updating or inserting?